# How to perform do-release-upgrade from 15.04 to 16.04 or later verions?

Tags: 15.04, 16.10

I have vivid 15.04. I tries the comments how to update and upgrade from the EOL versions such as vivid. I still get 404 error for repositories. I deactivatd PPAs , still the same problem.
I get "fail to update repository information check your internet"?

Comment: I noticed that http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid does not exists? But when I tried the comments to modify the repositories to old-releases.ubuntu.com , some lines are pointing to http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/vivid which does not exists ..

Comment: The best you can do is backup and install from scratch. The second best alternative is to boot a 16.04 live session, proceed to install as normally and at some point the installer should give an upgrade option.

Comment: I actually did that at the end. There seemed to be no other option or way. I tried an alternative release instead of vivid, and didn't work either (one time trial).